# Is there any "Find definition" in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder

In one of my projects we are using CodeGear C++ Builder 2009 from Embarcadero.
I am also working with Eclipse and VS2010.

Now there is one thing that I don't understand with C++ Builder (that I have no problem with in the other IDEs), isn't there any way to find a definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it wasn't until 2010, when they brought back the class explorer, that you could go to both the declaration and the definition of a class. That takes more steps than control-click, but is a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SourceNavigator http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/ for this purpose and more...